# Create a bar graph with filter

Tags: php, sql, phpgraphlib

I created a bar graph for fast moving and slowmoving products. I already load the graph, but when I filter the graph by month, the the image will no longer show.

I think `$_POST` method causes the error because when I put a static value to my query, the graph image will show.

Here is my code.

```
<?php include("phpgraphlib.php");
$graph=new PHPGraphLib(550,350);
include('myConnection.php'); 
$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];

$sql="SELECT menu_name, COUNT( * ) AS  'count'
FROM orders_menu AS om
INNER JOIN menu AS m ON m.menu_id_inc = om.menu_id_inc
WHERE MONTH(om.date_orderedmenu) =  '$month'
AND YEAR(om.date_orderedmenu) =  '$year'
GROUP BY menu_name";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$dataArray=array();
if ($result) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $menu=$row["menu_name"];
        $count=$row["count"];

        $dataArray[$menu]=$count;
        arsort($dataArray);
        array_slice($dataArray, 0,5); 
    }
}


$graph->addData($dataArray);
$graph->setDataValues(true);    
$graph->setTitle("Fast Moving Dishes");
$graph->setGradient("green", "olive");
$graph->setBarOutlineColor("black");
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

Comment: I check my POSTED variables if there are values and yes it has.  error image will show.

Comment: What error level display do you use?

Comment: I don't user error level. . What is that?

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);   and in php.ini display_errors = on

Comment: Same result i put it under my $_POSTED variables.

Comment: You have to add this code at the beginning of you script

Comment: done. . no errors show.

Comment: What output of "echo $sql;" ? Try copy the output and execute it in phpmyadmin or other mysql ide